# react-native-login-twitter was refused by TestFlight because it uses UIWebView

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

i used react-native-login-twitter but TestFlight doesn't accept this library because it uses UIWebView which (Deprecated API Usage in IOS ) :

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more

how can i solve this problem ?

there is no answers about this library :
https://github.com/clockin/react-native-login-twitter/issues/8

Comment: its only solution is implement WKWebView in place of UIWebView. go thorugh it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview

Comment: i can't sir because this library uses UIWebView and i can't change inside react-native-login-twitter

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a prop in webview in node_modules of react-native-login-twitter as
useWebKit={true}. If true, it will use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.

Comment: react-native-login-twitter  doesn't have a webview in source code